# extract attributes from list

Tags: python, list, extract

I am a novice in python and I treat to extract emotions from list and put each attribute to its corresponding series to train machine learning algorithms
for example this one instance in list and I want put anger in new series with its value= 0.013736263736263736 and so on.

"{'anger':",
'0.013736263736263736,',
"'anticipation':",
'0.0027472527472527475,',
"'disgust':",
'0.03296703296703297,',
"'fear':",
'0.0027472527472527475,',
"'joy':",
'0.0,',
"'negative':",
'0.06043956043956044,',
"'positive':",
'0.019230769230769232,',
"'sadness':",
'0.0027472527472527475,',
"'surprise':",
'0.008241758241758242,',
"'trust':",
'0.019230769230769232}']
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have no idea what this question is supposed to mean. You said something about "extracting" values from a list, but you did not show a list. In fact, I am not sure what data you are trying to show, because it is not valid Python syntax - the brackets don't balance properly. The way that quotes are used in this example also doesn't make very much sense. Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and show the data as code, and make sure you have *exactly* the data you want to ask about. Then show *exactly* what result you want.

Comment: After that, please read [ask], and make sure to **ask a question** in the body of your post. It should start with a question word like "how" or "why", and end with a question mark (`?`). "I want to..." [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate with dictionary and sentiment in many ways, let me show a few:

**1. Add item to collection**, sample

```
def calc_sentiment(word: str):
    return 0.5

def Add_to_Collection(sentense: str):
    sentiment={}
    for word in str.split(sentense):
        sentiment[word]=calc_sentiment(word)
    return sentiment

test='My name is John Cache. It is my real name.'
print(Add_to_Collection(test))
```

you can see outputs:

```
{'My': 0.5, 'name': 0.5, 'is': 0.5, 'John': 0.5, 'Cache.': 0.5, 'It': 0.5, 'my': 0.5, 'real': 0.5, 'name.': 0.5}
```

**2. Add item to collection with sum of sentiments**, sample

```
def calc_sentiment(word: str):
    return 0.5

def Add_to_Collection_Sum(sentense: str):
    sentiment={}
    for word in str.split(sentense):
        sentiment[word] = sentiment[word] + calc_sentiment(word)  if word in sentiment else calc_sentiment(word)
    return sentiment

test='My name is John Cache. It is my real name.'
print(Add_to_Collection_Sum(test))
```

you can see outputs (see value 1.0 for 'is'):

```
{'My': 0.5, 'name': 0.5, 'is': 1.0, 'John': 0.5, 'Cache.': 0.5, 'It': 0.5, 'my': 0.5, 'real': 0.5, 'name.': 0.5}
```

**3. Add item to collection with list of all sentiments**, sample

```
def calc_sentiment(word: str):
    return 0.5

def Add_to_Collection_AddToList(sentense: str):
    sentiment={}
    items=[]
    for word in str.split(sentense):
        if word in sentiment:
            items=sentiment[word]
            items.append(calc_sentiment(word))
        else:
            sentiment[word]=[calc_sentiment(word)]
    return sentiment

test='My name is John Cache. It is my real name.'
print(Add_to_Collection_AddToList(test))
```

you can see outputs (see double values [0.5, 0.5] for 'is'):

```
{'My': [0.5], 'name': [0.5], 'is': [0.5, 0.5], 'John': [0.5], 'Cache.': [0.5], 'It': [0.5], 'my': [0.5], 'real': [0.5], 'name.': [0.5]}
```